# Clear terminal window in Node.js readline shell

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, readline, read-eval-print-loop

I have a simple readline shell written in Coffeescript:

```coffee
rl = require 'readline'
cli = rl.createInterface process.stdin, process.stdout, null
cli.setPrompt "hello> "

cli.on 'line', (line) ->
  console.log line
  cli.prompt()

cli.prompt()
```

Running this displays a prompt:

```
$ coffee cli.coffee 
hello>
```

I would like to be able to hit `Ctrl-L` to clear the screen.  Is this possible?

I have also noticed that I cannot hit `Ctrl-L` in either the **node** or **coffee** REPLs either.

I am running on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can watch for the keypress yourself and clear the screen.

```
process.stdin.on 'keypress', (s, key) ->
  if key.ctrl && key.name == 'l'
    process.stdout.write '\u001B[2J\u001B[0;0f'
```

Clearing is done with ASCII control sequences like those written here:
http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

The first code `\u001B[2J` instructs the terminal to clear itself, and the second one `\u001B[0;0f` forces the cursor back to position 0,0.

#### Note

The `keypress` event is no longer part of the standard Node API in Node `>= 0.10.x` but you can use the [keypress](https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress) module instead.

Comment: This needed a `'\u001B[0;0f'` in there after the erase, but now works like a charm.  Thanks.

Comment: Didn't knew this exists! I almost wept on how beautiful that looks x')

Comment: I was removed after 0.8.x. I guess to much verbosity.

Comment: @stringparser See my note.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks! I've also discovered that this avliable on `core` library `readline`. Left an answer! :)

Answer (score 7):

This is the only answer that will clear the screen **AND** scroll history.

```
function clear() {
  // 1. Print empty lines until the screen is blank.
  process.stdout.write('\033[2J');

  // 2. Clear the scrollback.
  process.stdout.write('\u001b[H\u001b[2J\u001b[3J');
}

// Try this example to see it in action!
(function loop() {
  let i = -40; // Print 40 lines extra.
  (function printLine() {
    console.log('line ' + (i + 41));
    if (++i < process.stdout.columns) {
      setTimeout(printLine, 40);
    }
    else {
      clear();
      setTimeout(loop, 3000);
    }
  })()
})()
```

- The first line ensures the visible lines are always cleared.
- The second line ensures the scroll history is cleared.

Comment: This works perfectly for my needs. Thank you! I would suggest updating the `033` octal number above to `0o33` to make it work in JS strict mode as well.

Answer (score 6):

In the MAC terminal, to clear the console in NodeJS, you just hit `COMMAND+K` just like in Google Developer Tools Console so I'm guessing that on Windows it would be `CTRL+K`.

Comment: I think he means to clear the console prorammatically, not via user input.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the `COMMMAND+K` programmatically from Node?

Answer (score 4):

Try also:

```
var rl = require('readline');
rl.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, 0);
rl.clearScreenDown(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 3):

On response to @loganfsmyth comment on his answer (thanks for the edit!).

I have been looking here and there and, besides of the wonderfull [keypress](https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress) module, there is a core module that makes possible to create a `cli` with all standard terminal behavior (all things we give for granted today such as history, options to provide an auto-complete function and input events such as `keypress` are there).

The module is `readline` ([documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)). The good news is that all the standar behaviour is already done for us so there is no need to attach event handlers (i.e. history, clearing the screen on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, man if you provided the auto complete function it'll be on <kbd>Tab</kbd>press).

Just as an example

```
var readline = require('readline')
  , cli = readline.createInterface({
      input : process.stdin,
      output : process.stdout
  });

var myPrompt = ' > myPropmt '
cli.setPrompt(myPrompt, myPrompt.length); 
// prompt length so you can use "color" in your prompt
cli.prompt(); 
// Display ' > myPrompt ' with all standard features (history also!)

cli.on('line', function(cmd){ // fired each time the input has a new line       
   cli.prompt();
})

cli.input.on('keypress', function(key){  // self explanatory
  // arguments is a "key" object
  // with really nice properties such as ctrl : false
  process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(arguments))
});
```

Really good discovery.

The node version I'm using is `v0.10.29`. I have been looking at the [changelog](http://nodejs.org/changelog.html) and it was there since 2010 (commit [10d8ad](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/10d8ad)).

Answer (score 2):

You can clear screen using `console.log()` and escape sequences.

```
cli.on 'line', (line) ->
  if line == 'cls'
    console.log("\033[2J\033[0f")
  else
    console.log line
cli.prompt()
```

Answer (score 2):

[Vorpal.js](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) makes things like this really easy.

For an interactive CLI with a `clear` command as well as a REPL within the context of your application, do this:

```
var vorpal = require('vorpal')();
var repl = require('vorpal-repl');

vorpal
  .delimiter('hello>')
  .use(repl)
  .show();

vorpal
  .command('clear', 'Clears the screen.')
  .action(function (args, cb) {
    var blank = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < process.stdout.rows; ++i) {
      blank += '\n';
    }
    vorpal.ui.rewrite(blank);
    vorpal.ui.rewrite('');
    cb();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `readline.createInterface` you could do something like:

```js
function clearPrompt() {
  rl.setPrompt("");
  rl.prompt();
}
```

Note this won't clear the entire terminal, just the readline prompt. Still useful if you want the user to keep their place in the terminal