# STDOUT gets in front of STDIN while prompting?

Tags: node.js, stdout, stdin, prompt

I have a setInterval who logs the time every second.
I want to use STDIN to execute commands in my script, but the STDOUT is moving the cursor while I'm typing and puts itself in the prompt.

I don't have much experience with prompts, just started diving into this.

Script:

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(new Date().toUTCString());
},1000)

var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Hi there, how are you?", function(answer) {

});
```

Output:

```
Hi there, how are you?Mon, 17 Dec 2012 16:20:34 GMT
fine
Mon, 17 Dec 2012 16:20:35 GMT
Mon, 17 Dec 2012 16:20:36 GMT
Mon, 17 Dec 2012 16:20:37 GMT
Mon, 17 Dec 2012 16:20:38 GMT
```

How would you solve something like this? Cache all the STDOUT, clear the screen, write all the STDOUT and prompt again every time console.log() is logging?

Yes I do want to create some kind of chat based system/command line interface where the output stays above the input.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to simultaneously be logging to stdout and typing? Maybe log to a file instead? Your input should still work even if it is spread across a few lines visually.

Comment: Lets say I want to create some kind of chat client that works in the terminal, I dont necessary want to log my input, but there is logging going on because of other factors (like other users for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you are asking is how to make a complex terminal application. The most popular library for this is called `ncurses` and it has [node bindings here](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ncurses). I don't have personal experience using it unfortunately.

Your other option would be to do as your said, and manually re-render the terminal using your own internal buffers. You can get the size of the output terminal using Node's `tty` module, [docs here](http://nodejs.org/api/tty.html), and then use [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to clear the terminal, position the cursor where you want, and then use `process.stdout.write` to print what you want.

You can see an example of using escape codes in my other question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813142/clear-terminal-window-in-node-js-readline-shell/8813316#8813316)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, so I guess that's the way to do it then. Do you think re-rendering the terminal is also the technique being used in other complex terminal applications like the Eggdrop partyline via telnet for example?